# How to generate symbol table with arm gcc

Tags: gcc, arm, embedded

I would like to create a symbol definition table to be used in a separate application during linking. ARM's armlink linker has the following flag but I'm using arm-eabi:

> [--symdefs=*filename*](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0803b/Chddaidi.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This the correct answer from arm gnu launchpad:

Do you intend to load the symdef file with the GNU toolchain or with armcc one? If the former I think using nm on the object file and then linking with `-R <filename>` would work. So you would do `arm-none-eabi-nm -D ./prog > ./prog.defsym` after linking prog and then `arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wl,-R,./prog.defsym` when you want to use this.

Comment: ARMLINK sym file is in text format:
0x000011cd T get_active_ota_bank_addr
0x00001a17 T SHA256_Init
0x00001a33 T SHA256_Update

gcc -R doesn't accept it
it says: file format not recognized; treating as linker script

Answer (score 3):

The GNU [objcopy utility](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/objcopy.html#objcopy) has an option `--extract-symbol` that may do what you want. It generates an object file with only symbol data - no actual code or data.

It is specifically intended to generate a .sym file for use in the VxWorks RTOS which has a command shell and dynamic linker/loader that uses this information.  It is also used by the VxWorks host shell and source-level debugger.

The [binutils nm utility](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/nm.html) on the other hand generates output very similar to armlink's `--symdefs` which you might easily post-process into exactly the form you need.

Answer (score 1):

`-Wl,-Map -Wl,mapfile -Wl,--cref`

added to the final gcc (link) command line should do the trick.

Comment: I require the format to be accepted by the linker. I tried readelf --syms file.elf > sym.def. But this isnt accepted by the linker only:  symbol = address;

Comment: I'm afraid there is no binutils tool that generates listings in exactly the same format you want (directly accepted as linker command file). You probably need some reformatting. You might try if `objdump -t` better suits your needs.

Comment: if you want to reference symbols defined in another object file which you don't want to include it in the link, add it with `--just-symbols=<object>` to your linker command line. The symbols are then resolved as absolute addresses if that is what you want.